# Android Studio, Firebase Phone Authentication Opening A Browser?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add phone authentication in my app using Firebase, When I click the send OTP button a browser is opening saying verifying that you are not a robot and only after I verify that I am not a robot by selecting the images, it is sending an OTP.

And also the format of OTP has changed.

**Previously the OTP format was**

**435325 is your verification code for MyApplication.**

**New format of OTP is**

**789574 if your verification code for myapplication.55b19.firebaseapp.com**

I just don't understand why a browser is opening every time I request for an OTP

Here is my code

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText phoneEt,otpEt;
    Button loginBtn,verifyOTPBtn;
    private String verificationCodeBySystem;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        phoneEt = findViewById(R.id.phoneEt);
        otpEt = findViewById(R.id.otpEt);
        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        verifyOTPBtn = findViewById(R.id.verifyOTPBtn);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String phoneNumber = phoneEt.getText().toString().trim();
                sendOTPCodeToUser(phoneNumber);
            }
        });

        verifyOTPBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code = otpEt.getText().toString().trim();
                if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6){
                    otpEt.setError("Wrong OTP...");
                    otpEt.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        });
    }


    private void sendOTPCodeToUser(String phoneNumber) {
        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber("+91"+phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationCodeBySystem = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            verifyCode(code);



        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

        }
    };

    private void verifyCode(String code) {

        try{
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationCodeBySystem,code);
            signInTheCredentials(credential);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }


    }

    private void signInTheCredentials(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

**Gradle file**

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"

    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'

}
```

Comment: Hey, Did you guys solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable safety net in your Google cloud console for using phone auth as per this [Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=1#enable-app-verification)